# unable to pass arguments inside reject in sinon test case

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, sinon, chai

Here is the piece of node.js code that i am tryiny to test using  sinon, chai , mocha,.
How ever i am not understanding as to why i am unable to pass parameters in the reject of sinon . I tried looking for online help as well as documentation but still unable to get appropriate reason. Here is the code that i am trying to test :

```
this.retrieveSomething =  function () {
  var promiseFunc = function (resolve, reject) { 
    Repository.findSomething( {$or: [{"status":"x"},{"status":"y"}]}, 'name description status')
      .then(function (result) {
        resolve(result);
      })
      .catch(function (err) {
        reject(new errors.InternalServerError('Failed to find Surveys',
          {errors: [{message: 'Failed  '}, {details: err.errors}]}));
      });
  };

  return new Promise(promiseFunc);
};
```

here is the test code

```
it('failure', function (done) {
  var findSomethingStub = sinon.stub(Repository, 'findSomething');
  findSomethingStub.returnsPromise().rejects();

  var promise = fixture.retrieveSurveysVast();
  setTimeout(function () {
    expect(findSomethingStub.calledOnce).to.be.true;
    expect(promise).to.be.eventually.deep.equal("failed");
    Repository.findSomething.restore();
    done();
  }, 5);
});
```

This case passes successfully. However this is acting strange, if i try to reject it this way

```
findSomethingStub.returnsPromise().rejects("failed");
```

and match it like this

```
expect(promise).to.be.eventually.deep.equal("failed");
```

it says

```
Unhandled rejection InternalServerError: Failed to find Surveys
```

infact it does not matter what i give inside equal. please help as to why i am unable to pass arguments to reject and expect it to equal to the same argument.

Answer (score 1):

I hope my answer here would be useful.
Looking at your test script.. first, you stubbed `Repository.findSomething` to returns rejected promise with string 'failed'. Therefore, in the actual `this.retrieveSomething` code, it will fall into the catch statement:

```
.catch(function (err) {
        reject(new errors.InternalServerError('Failed to find Surveys',
          {errors: [{message: 'Failed  '}, {details: err.errors}]}));
      });
```

That means, the (err) will contains string 'failed' as the result of rejected promise you stubbed. After that, `this.retrieveSomething` will return promise reject, but the value of it will be processed by function `error.InternalServerError` that takes 2 arguments as above. Therfore, the rejected value of function `this.retrieveSomething` depends on your implementation of `error.InternalServerError`.

Another thing to note, I think your rejected stub `findSomethingStub.returnsPromise().rejects("failed");` wont take any effect since the error.InternalServerError will grab `err.errors` so at least it should be like this: `findSomethingStub.returnsPromise().rejects({errors: "failed"});`

I've tried to simulate your code by **assuming** that error.InternalServerError  returns a string like this:

```
class Errors {
    InternalServerError(string, obj) {
        return `error: ${string}, message: ${obj.errors[0].message}, details: ${obj.errors[1].details}`;
    } }
```

Then, in the test case I try

```
const fixture = require('../47573532-sinon-react/Fixture');
const Repository = require('../47573532-sinon-react/Repository');
const chai = require('chai');
const sinon = require('sinon');
const sinonChai = require('sinon-chai');
const chaiAsPromised = require('chai-as-promised');
const sinonStubPromise = require('sinon-stub-promise');

sinonStubPromise(sinon);
chai.use(chaiAsPromised);
chai.use(sinonChai);
chai.should();

describe('/47573532-sinon-react', () => {
    it('failure (using sinon, chai, sinon-stub-promise, chai-as-promised)', (done) => {
        const findSomethingStub = sinon.stub(Repository, 'findSomething');
        findSomethingStub.returnsPromise().rejects({ errors: 'failed' });
        const promise = fixture.retrieveSurveysVast();

        promise.should.be.rejected.then((err) => {
            err.should.be.deep.equal
            (
                'error: Failed to find Surveys, message: Failed  , details: failed'
            );
            findSomethingStub.restore();
        }).should.notify(done);
    });
});
```

First, it will assert that promise.should.be.rejected, then it evaluates the err based on InternalServerError implementation result. In this case we need to make sure that `details: 'failed'` is match with what the stubbed rejects. if we change the `details` value with something else, the test will fail.

```
it('failure (using sinon, chai, sinon-stub-promise, chai-as-promised)', (done) => {
        const findSomethingStub = sinon.stub(Repository, 'findSomething');
        findSomethingStub.returnsPromise().rejects({ errors: 'failed' });
        const promise = fixture.retrieveSurveysVast();

        promise.should.be.rejected.then((err) => {
            err.should.be.deep.equal
            (
                'error: Failed to find Surveys, message: Failed  , details: something not from stub'
            ); // this will cause test failed
            findSomethingStub.restore();
        }).should.notify(done);
    });
```